# What is work from source means?

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

I found [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html).
I had looked ["work from" or "work in"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15678/work-from-or-work-in), but I did not know this sentence means…

Comment: **from** there is used to refer to a place of origin as in "We must go *from* London to Manchester." or to a "source" or "basis" as in *Petroleum is produced from fossilized vegetation.*   The running executable is produced *from* "source code", the human-readable instructions that are compiled down to instructions which the computer understands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the "wiki" link it will guide you on how to download the source code.
That is what is meant by "source".